# JavaFX 1.3: CRUD using ListView

Tags: listview, crud, javafx

I've got 2 problems. I'm trying to create a crud with a `ListView`. [Now here's how I want my UI to look](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/202/listviewcrud.png/).

I created this with the following code:

```
var studentManagementListView: ListView = ListView {
        items: ["bla", "bla", "bla", "bla", "bla", "bla", "bla", "bla", "bla", "bla", "bla"]
        cellFactory: function() {
            def listCell: ListCell = ListCell {
                        node: HBox {
                            spacing: 10
                            content: [
                                Label {
                                    text: bind if (listCell.empty) then "" else "{listCell.item}"
                                    visible: bind not listCell.selected and not listCell.empty
                                }
                                TextBox {
                                    text: bind listCell.item.toString()
                                    columns: 12
                                    visible: bind listCell.selected and not listCell.empty
                                    selectOnFocus: true
                                }
                                SwingComboBox {
                                    visible: bind listCell.selected and not listCell.empty

                                    items: for (classItem in classes) {
                                        SwingComboBoxItem {
                                            selected: false
                                            text: classItem.toString()
                                            value: classItem
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                                Button {
                                    text: "delete"
                                    visible: bind listCell.selected and not listCell.empty
                                    action: function() {

                                    }
                                }
                                Button {
                                    text: "save"
                                    visible: bind listCell.selected and not listCell.empty
                                    action: function() {

                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
        }
    };
```

Now here are the troubles I'm having.

1. The `SwingComboBox` is acting very strange, it only opens up when the `ListCell` is freshly selected. It's also impossible to select a `SwingComboBoxItem`.
2. How can I access the "text" variable inside the save button action? or any other variable (like the selected `ComboBox`)? I tried defining the ListCell outside the `ListView` and generally define everything outside the `ListView` so I can easily use everything but I got some error saying that some things were already defined.

Basically for the second problem I just want to know how to fill a `ListView` in a different way then I'm doing now.

I haven't really found anything of use on the google machine. If anyone can help I'd appreciate it!